# How to write a "Hello World" app with .net compact framework for Windows Embedded Compact 7?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

I want to write a "Hello World" app with .net compact framework for windows embedded compact 7. Now I have download Windows embedded compact 7 and install it to C:\WINCE700.  Also I can create a "OSDesign1" solution with my VS2008SP1. It compiled succeed and generated a file named "nk.bin".

I don't know what the next step to do.  Could you tell me how to do it?  I'm a newer for Windows Compact 7. Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you have a device to run it on?

Answer (score 0):

You need a device to run the OS that you've created or you may use virtual machine. Refer to the following link on how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200363.aspx

you may also refer the documentation found in:

..%Program Files%\Windows Embedded Compact 7\Documentation

sample Hello world app in Advanced Virtual CEPC.pdf